# Assume c ∈ (0, 1) is given. What is inf {c^n |n ∈ N }?

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble proving this. I know that an infimum is defined as the greatest lower bound such that if the infimum = s, then for all x in our set, s <= x, but I don't know how to prove that for this specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}c^n=0$.

Also, the function $f(n)=x^n$ is decreasing for all $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: The infimum then is zero. So then the proof would just need to show that zero is less than or equal to everything in the set?

Comment: @user180069: Yes the inf is $0$, and it is definitely less than any positive number :). $c^n$ are all positive. However, for $0$ to be the inf, it's not just sufficient to check that. Remember that any negative number would satisfy this condition as well. Read the definition of inf a bit more carefully, and see what you need to prove.

Comment: $x^n$ is increasing on $(0,1)$, did you mean $f(n)=x^n$ is decreasing for all $x\in(0,1)$?

Comment: @DavidPeterson: Yes that's what I meant. Let me edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The infimum is the largest possible lower bound. It's clear $L = 0$ is a lower bound. Suppose we have a lower bound $L > 0$. Then for all $n$ we have $0< L < c^n$. But you can make $c^n$ as close to zero as you like, in fact you can make $c^n < L$ for $n$ large enough. So no lower bound greater than zero exists.